# Getting the name of the day based on the value in a previous cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to get day name (Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.) based on the value of another cell?

I have a spreadsheet for projecting work status.  I populate a cell, for example "F3" called "Start Date", and then I display the name of the day of the week in another cell using "=TEXT(F3,"ddd").

I then want to place the name of the day of the week in the remaining cells in the row.   I did it, rather clumsily, by putting the same formula in those cells and incrementing by a value of one, id est - =TEXT(F3+1,"ddd"), =TEXT(F3+2,"ddd"), and so on out to a value of +31, as that is presently the number of days addressed.

I'm am looking for a more elegant way to accomplish the task.   Any suggestions appreciated.

Respectfully,

Fergie

Comment: Welcome Ferg - Did the answer below help you? If so, then please mark as answered by selecting the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the column count itself, that will save you from manually increasing the value:
`=TEXT(F3+COLUMN(),"ddd")`

You might need to subtract a constant, as you are not starting in column 1:
`=TEXT(F3+COLUMN()-5,"ddd")`
or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with "Start Date" in F3 then you can use absolute referencing based on this (use $F$3) so when you drag the formula then this starting point does not change.

Formula next to F3 is in G3 assuming you are going across columns in same row. So column G will have the Start Dates day (hence -1 in formula) below.

[image: excel view of layout]

Formula in G3:

```
=TEXT($F$3+COLUMN()-COLUMN($F$3)-1,"ddd")
```

Then you copy or drag this single formula across from column H onwards.

So Formula in G3:

[image: G3 formula]